# node.js redis asynchronous calls

Tags: node.js, redis, nodes, node-redis

I'm fetching data from my database using redis in a foor loop like this.

```
client.smembers(user_key, function(err, reply) {
      console.log("1");
      for(var i=0; i < reply.length; i++) {
        console.log("2");
        client.hgetall(reply[i], function(error, object) {
            console.log("3");
            // Do stuff
        });
      }
      console.log("4");
});
```

The problem is that redis is asynchronous and the foor loop doesn't wait for redis to finish fetching data. So for example if `reply` is `["user_1", "user_2"]` this would be the output:

```
1
2
2
4
3
```

How can I force the loop to wait for redis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[underscore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore)** :: [each()](http://underscorejs.org/#each) :

```
const _ = require('underscore')
client.smembers(user_key, function(err, reply) {
  _.each(reply,function(element, index){
     client.hgetall(element, function(error, object) {
        // Do stuff
     })
  })
})
```